# How to print the name of my current directory's parent directory

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I hope I phrased my question clearly. Specifically, it is this:

I would like to use test or perhaps a case statement to determine if a directory name contained in the variable $DIR is either my current directory (.) or it's parent directory (..)

Of course I can echo my current directory (echo $PWD), but what is the simplest way to echo the parent of $PWD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `${PWD%/*}`:

```
$ echo $PWD
/home/me/test/t
$ echo ${PWD%/*}
/home/me/test
```

As the expression `${PWD%/*}` is stripping the shortest match of `/*` from back of `$PWD`:

From [Bash Reference Manual → 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **${parameter%word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Answer (score 2):

```
dirname $PWD
```

or

```
dirname $(pwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`realpath`](http://man.cx/realpath)

```
parent=$(realpath "$PWD/..")
```

Comment: Please provide come documentation to explain "how" this answers the question.